# Bluetooth Low Energy - BluetoothGattCallback onConnectionStateChanged() never called

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I´m currently trying to create a BLE connection for a project in school. I´m new to coding and it´s my first time to program a BLE-Connection. I used the Android Developer instructions and it´s currently possible to scan for BLE-Devices and try to connect. But the onConnectionStateChanged() is never called, so I´m not able to connect to the device. I already read some similar questions on StackOverflow from others with the same problem, but the suggested solutions couldn´t help me. I also read that´s it could be a problem with Android 12+, but i also couldn´t find any solutions for it.

This is my code, it may be a little confusing for experienced people, but I'm not that experienced yet and currently just want the code to work before I write everything into subprograms

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"  android:required="true" />
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final UUID BT_MODULE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    private final String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
    private final String LIST_UUID = "UUID";

    private Button mScanBtn;
    private Button mListPairedDevicesBtn;
    private Button mDiscoverBtn;
    private Button mDisconnect;
    private ListView mDevicesListView;

    private BluetoothLeService bluetoothService;
    private String deviceAddress;
    boolean connected;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBTAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mScanner;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mBTArrayAdapter;
    private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> GattCharacteristics =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();


    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean scanning;
    private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
            mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            mBTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mScanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_BT_ON);
        mListPairedDevicesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_paireddvc);
        mDiscoverBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_discover_dvc);
        mDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_disconnect);
        mDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_devicelist);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mBTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        bluetoothManager  = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBTAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        mScanner = mBTAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        mDevicesListView.setAdapter(mBTArrayAdapter);
        mDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if(mBTAdapter==null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Device does not support Bluetooth");
        }
        else{
            mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                        {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE}, 2);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                        {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 2);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    bluetoothDiscoverable();
                }
            });
            mListPairedDevicesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                        {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 2);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    listPairedDevices();
                }
            });
            mDiscoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                        {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 2);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    discover();
                }
            });
            mDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    bluetoothService.disconnect();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(gattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
        if (bluetoothService != null) {
            final boolean result = bluetoothService.connect(deviceAddress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(gattUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bluetoothService.close();
        unregisterReceiver(gattUpdateReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(b1receiver);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            deviceAddress = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
            mScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), deviceAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 2);
                    return;
                }
            }
            bluetoothService.connect(deviceAddress);

        }
    };

    private void bluetoothDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBTAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(b1receiver,intentFilter);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device is now discoverable for 300 seconds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void discover(){
        if(!scanning){
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scanning = false;
                    mScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            scanning = true;
            mScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }else{
            scanning = false;
            mScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private void listPairedDevices(){
        mBTArrayAdapter.clear();
        mPairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // put it's one to the adapter
            for (BluetoothDevice device : mPairedDevices)
                mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver b1receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals(ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)){
                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    //Device is in discoverable Mode
                    case SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discoverability Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    //Device not in discoverable mode
                    case SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discoverability Enabled. Able to receive connections", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discoverability Disabled. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver gattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                connected = true;
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                connected = false;
            }else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICE_DISCOVERED.equals(action)){
                //displayGattServices(bluetoothService.getSupportedGattServices());
            }
        }
    };


    private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            bluetoothService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (bluetoothService != null) {
                if(!bluetoothService.initialize()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                bluetoothService.connect(deviceAddress);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connect() not called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bluetoothService = null;
        }
    };
 private IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        return intentFilter;
    }
}
```

BluetoothLeService:

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICE_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    private int connectionState;
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
    private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter;
    private BluetoothManager BTManager;
    public String BluetoothDeviceAddress;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GattCallback called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                // successfully connected to the GATT Server
                connectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                // disconnected from the GATT Server
                connectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Connection possible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICE_DISCOVERED);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onServiceDiscovered received: "+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
             {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE,characteristic);
        }
    };

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public boolean initialize() {
        BTManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BTAdapter = BTManager.getAdapter();
        if (BTAdapter == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean connect(String address) {
        if (BTAdapter == null || address == null) {
            return false;
        }
        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (BluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(BluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && bluetoothGatt != null) {
            if (bluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                connectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        BluetoothDevice device = BTAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ConnectGatt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this,false,bluetoothGattCallback,2);
        }
        connectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        BluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        return true;
    }


    public void disconnect() {
        if (BTAdapter == null || bluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void close() {
        if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        bluetoothGatt.close();
        bluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices(){
        if(bluetoothGatt==null){
            return null;
        }
        return bluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }

    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,boolean enabled) {
        if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BluetoothGatt not initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
    }

    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BluetoothGatt not initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

}
```

I tried some suggested solutions like to stop the Scan when i want to connect to the device, or to call up the runtime permission before i want to establish the connection.

Comment: If this project is for school purposes, the runtime permissions can be given manually from your app's settings. You can do it so for your convenience in case you don't want to implement handling of runtime permissions.